# Transistor as an AND gate

Tags: transistors

I am just wondering if a transistor works similar to an AND gate. I read on a website saying that the voltage coming into the collector and base would give voltage to the emitter. This sounds similar to an AND gate. Am I correct?

Comment: A transistor on its own isn't quite like a gate, but particular transistor *circuits* can act like gates. Different types of circuits connect the emitter, collector, and base differently. Can you show the specific circuit you're talking about?

Comment: [Transistor](https://www.101computing.net/creating-logic-gates-using-transistors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's fair to the transistor to say that it's like *any* kind of gate!

There are so many ways that a transistor can be connected to signal sources and power supply voltages that you can configure it to be "like" many different things.

With a few extra components, like diodes and resistors, you can make the transistor do NOT, AND, NAND, OR and NOR! You can also make it amplify voltages by multiplying.

It's really much more than a "single function" device. Everything depends on how you connect it, and what else you connect around it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'You can also make it amplify voltages by multiplying.'

Comment: If instead of using the transistor as a on/off switch (in digital context), you place the transistor in an intermediate state, it can respond to small changes in a signal's voltage with a proportionally large voltage change, called "amplification", the factor by which it multiplies the input amplitude being called "gain".

Answer (score 0):

No, actually the emitter voltage gets set by the base voltage not the collector voltage.